# Trying input { or } within c# editor (in VS) using Alt codes is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editing

I try to type { or } with the alt123, alt125 (that here within are workly fine as you can see) in the Visual Studio c# editor but what happen is that the cursor run somewhere else in the code, seems that add a tab character there together with another character : ☺ (this I cut and paste from the code)

Comment: Works fine for me (US keyboard), but when I add a `{` in C# source, VS automatically adds the `}`  and formats the line

Comment: Ok . Te point is that to add { o  } I have to cut from somewhere else and paste ther where I need to.

Comment: What keyboard are you using that doesn't know about curly braces? Might those characters be available under some "alt" key or something?

Comment: Keybord is ok . Now I write it here with the usual alt123 :     {  and now with alt 125 :    }  , then all other application (notepad ...) don't give the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you could always get a set of curly braces then drag them onto your toolbox (to create a tool) on the left of your screen in visual studio. That way when you need them again you can just double click on them in the toolbox to insert them into your code. See the picture below.

[image: Create tool in visual studio for curly braces]

Or create a snippit in visual studio for them?